# Curl won't prompt me for a certificate password

Tags: curl, client-certificate

I'm trying to use CURL to test simple HTTPS connections to servers that require a client certificate.  I've specified the certificate type in my `.curlrc` file with `cert = /path/to/Cert.p12` and told it that yes, it's a PKCS12 cert with `cert-type = P12`.  It kept failing with "could not parse PKCS12 file, check password...... mac verify failure", so out of curiosity I tried hard-coding the password in the config file, and sure enough it pulled the page right up.

I read [the man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) about a dozen times and I can't see anything from the command line to say "please prompt me for a password", and it says right there "If the optional password isn't specified, it will be queried for on the terminal".  Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find a source, but it appears that while CURL *sort of* speaks PKCS12, it would really rather have a PEM-format cert.  Simply converting my PKCS12 cert to PEM, with password, caused CURL to start prompting for passwords as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to use a P12 and I use an environment variable for the password, which I obtain via a secure prompt ahead of time. Code:

```
read -sp "Certificate Password: " CERTPASS
curl --cert-type P12 --cert myp12file.p12:"$CERTPASS" https://example.com
```

Also, I was able to get it to prompt for a certificate password with this command format:

```
curl -uadmin -v -X POST https://example.com
```